# What does "persuade you otherwise" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "persuade you otherwise" mean exactly?
Is it an idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, but it sounds like something that might have sexual undertones.  "May I persuade you otherwise" means roughly, "May I convince you to change your mind about this?"  It's less wordy than the idiomatic 'change your mind', and it sounds more eloquent.

Comment: Thanks @Wolfpack'08.
It's here [link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/07/16-pixels-body-copy-anything-less-costly-mistake/). 
"I'd like to persuade you otherwise"

Comment: Most readers assume 12 pixels is ideal, as opposed to 16 pixels.  He wants to persuade them otherwise: convincing you that 16 pixels is ideal.  Note that that huge red block is an "I".  'I know what you're thinking!  "Did he say 16 pixels?"...'

Comment: I detect no sexual overtones in the expression in normal use.

Comment: Everyone's entitled to their opinion.  Feel free.  Here's my explanation of why I think persuade is a sexually-charged word:  If you consider the synonyms, induce (labor), convince (con), prevail (conquer), you can see a some thought-provoking shades of contrast.  Persuade is much more charming, and I feel it's used more frequently with charming characters in literature, than its alternatives.  Suade also sounds like 'suede', which is lamb skin--not only does it feel lush, but it's used to make condoms.  Also, thought to be a way of 'guiding' somebody, the word 'persuade' sounds... intimate.

Answer (score 0):

persuade you otherwise - to give an alternate option over something that is already discussed,

e.g Mr. X wants to buy a property in this region but the Realtor wishes to persuade him otherwise.